# Unable to read BLOB Image from mysql database using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, blob

I am trying to read a columns of the type BLOB from mysql database . I get the below error when i try to display it using ajax. Not sure what is wrong ?

I am making a jquery ajax post call to the php located on the webserver which connects to the mysql database on the server.

Error

```
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home2/marshell/public_html/xyz.com/php/readProfilePicture.php on line 12

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home2/marshell/public_html/xyz.com/php/readProfilePicture.php on line 15
```

readProfilePicture.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "marshell_dpouch", "pass", "xyz", "3306");

$email = "xyz@gmail.com";

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_select_db($db,"xyz");

$sql = "SELECT Image FROM profileinformation WHERE email = '".$email."' ";
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);

echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['Image'] ).'" height="300" width="200" >';

?>
```

Ajax

```
$.post("http://www.example.com/php/readProfilePicture.php",
  {

  },
    function(data,status){

      $("#displayprofilepicturehere").html(data);

    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of your code:

```
$con->select_db("xyz");
```

This code:

```
mysqli_select_db($db,"xyz");
```

is old-style, if you're not using MySQLi object.

And than you have another error:

```
$sth = $db->query($sql);
```

Choose one object name: `$con` or `$db` and use it everywhere in your script. I think, you have a typo. May be in the beginning this is:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "marshell_dpouch", "pass", "xyz", "3306");
```

Comment: +1 for spotting the `$db` un-initialized error. Can't call something that isn't there!

Answer (score 1):

I belive this will solve your problem

```
mysqli_select_db($con ,"xyz"); and not mysqli_select_db($db,"xyz");
```